# After checking out a git branch, do remote FTP changes only affect branch or master too?

Tags: git, svn, github, version-control, ftp

Dev for a long time, but making the switch to Git for version control.

Forgive my probably painfully obvious question here, but given the scenario below, how does git behave?

If I create a branch, 'A', and check out said branch, if I then open an FTP client, download a file, make some changes and re-upload it (or remote edit it from Sublime with an FTP plugin), has master been changed at this point or just the branch? What happens if someone else makes edits to that file on our dev server while I have the branch checked out?

My gut says that you can't have multiple people editing physical files on the same server but have to clone local or to a dev server they're spun up for their own editing (even though that seems horribly inefficient). I'm just trying to make sure I've wrapped my brain around the git concepts well enough.

When I dev'd SAP, 'transports' got created that had changes tracked in them, but everyone was editing the same file on the same server yet the transports kept track of what changes were made and by who so you never had to clone files anywhere. Not sure Git works in the same manner.

Any clarification on this topic would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how git works :

When you fetch a branch from remote, say `branchA`, and checkout to that branch, you actually are looking at your local copy of that branch. To be precise, `origin/branchA` is the remote branch, `branchA` is your local copy of the branch. Now in your case your local copy is actually in a remote machine to which you ftp and make changes. Once you change a file say `file1` in your current branch, your uncommitted changes will include `file1`.

If many people are ftp'ing into the same machine, ofc everyone will see that change because that's how ftp works. Once you commit the file and push it to `origin/branchA`, your remote branch gets the committed change.

Unlike svn, you don't rely on a central server in git. Everyone clones a copy of the remote repo, make changes to their local copy in their local machine and push changes to remote. Others pull the code on a collaborative basis to get the changes at the time of need and add their changes and so on. That's why it's called decentralized version control.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. While I know tech like Docker is exploding for this very reason, it's still difficult for me to understand how a dev can work on multiple projects and be expected to edit locally - how do you make sure your local settings match the dev server you're pushing changes to?

Comment: When a user makes changes and pushes to remote, the remote branch gets one commit ahead and the local branch of another user who doesn't have the commit is one commit behind. So when he tries to push his changes, git won't accept it. But simply, he'll be asked to pull before pushing. That way, the order of the commits will be maintained in the remote as well as all the local copies in different dev machines at any point in time.